# extjs get height of viewport panel

Tags: extjs

**I want a specific height(600px,etc) of the middle content on page load:**

**Right now I have something similar to:**

[***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___***Header****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**]

[Left Sidebar]   [Middle Content Panel]    [Right Sidebar]

[***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___***Footer****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**]

**Part of the code:**

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    id: 'parent_container',
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        contentEl: 'header',
        border: false
    }, {
        region: 'west',
        id: 'left_sidebar_panel',
        split: true,
        width: 200,
        minSize: 200,
        maxSize: 400,
        autoScroll: true,
        contentEl: 'sidebar_container',
        border: false
    },{
        region: 'center',
        id: 'middle_content_panel',
        layout: 'border',
        border: false,
        items: [{
            region: 'north',
            contentEl: 'main_content_header',
            border: false
    }...
```

Is there anyway to force middle_content_panel to have a specific height on page load/window expand? Or a way to grab the height of it with javascript some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to define your center content as variable

```
For example: var center= new Ext.Panel({
...
});
```

You can use setHeight Method `center.setHeight(600);`

From Documentation:

[image]